# Parse shtml as SSI, but also include PHP using .htaccess

Tags: php, ssi, shtml

I have a particular situation with code i'm inheriting which is using shtml server-side-include, however I'm attempting to add some very simple login functionality to the site so I need to include a session check in PHP.

However my the only configuration I can do to the server is the .htaccess file.

I can get the server to parse the shtml as PHP using htaccess, OR use SSI however I cannot get it to parse it as both.

Comment: Why would you expect that the server could use more than one handler to parse the file?

Comment: Who said expect? This is a question site.

Comment: PHP usually runs as handler. But Apache has a concept of filters. Investigate this.

Comment: On my local server it actually works, once I allow shtml to be parsed as PHP. So I'm trying to mimic that on the remote-server ( which I only have access to via FTP and htaccess )

Answer (score 2):

This .htaccess configuration worked, allowing the server to use more than one handler to parse the file. As expected.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .shtml
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
```

Comment: I use the .sphp file extension for a web page which is written in PHP but which uses Server-Side Includes:   

https://sealevel.info/binomcalc.sphp   

Just as .shtml is HTML with Server-Side Includes, .sphp is PHP with Server-Side Includes (CGI Perl).