# Parse both SSI and PHP in specific .php file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, file, ssi

I'm looking for a way to parse both SSI (which is usually in .shtml files) and PHP in one of my PHP files.

In `.htaccess`, I'm using this to add SSI parsing to my PHP file, but when I do that, the PHP stops working and behaves as HTML comments with only the SSI parsing as expected.

```
<Files phpfile.php>
    AddHandler server-parsed .php
</Files>
```

How can I add both parsing methods into this file?

*EDIT: There are [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713204/parse-shtml-as-ssi-but-also-include-php-using-htaccess) here regarding the opposite (PHP in `.shtml` files), but firstly, that solution didn't work for me, and secondly I'd preferably like it the other way around.*

I am running Apache 2.4 with CloudLinux, Litespeed and cPanel.

Comment: [Maybe this article has an approach.](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/php/php_ssi.htm)  I like the idea of using `virtual`.

Comment: @cerebriform thanks, but I need to parse SSI direct in the file, not just including shtml files into the php file. This should be possible in the .htaccess file I guess, but I'm not very good at that.

Comment: This question is about doing the same thing (I think) but for .shtml files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713204/parse-shtml-as-ssi-but-also-include-php-using-htaccess

Comment: @kainaw, well, maybe I could change filename to shtml and do it like that. I don't know how to change this piece of code to the other way around, though, which would be the best solution.

Comment: @kainaw I just tried the php-in-shtml-solution, but the code didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the order you wish to execute this in.

If you are intending to have a file parsed for SSI directives, and then interpreted as PHP, this is not possible, as PHP operates at the file-system level.

If you intend to have the output of a PHP process parsed for SSI directives, there are some ways to do this.  The linked question is one of them, there is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560326/ssi-included-in-php-as-template-not-working?rq=1) answer, which may be something that will work for you.

The former works because Apache is able to take the output of PHP, parse it for SSI directives, satisfy those directives, and then output it to the client.  However, it is not possible to do the reverse.  Also note that no files included as a result of SSI includes will be parsed for PHP first.  Only the initial request.

Perhaps more important would be to determine exactly what problem you are trying to solve here.  What has put you in the place that you need to do this?  And would it be possible to solve this problem with strictly PHP or SSI.

PHP has a number of built-in functions for doing similar tasks, `include` and `require`.  It also has the [`virtual` command](http://php.net/manual/en/function.virtual.php), which will execute an Apache sub-request.  This sub-request will be handled as Apache is configured, and if the file called in `virtual` is an SHTML file, it will be parsed for SSI directives.

It is important to note, however, that the `virtual` command will flush all data to the client prior to including the file, and the result of the include will be sent directly to the client (PHP will not have access to the output of the command, and the SHTML file will not have access to any PHP data [or vice versa]).

Comment: Okay, but I can't manage to get PHP output in the .shtml file either using the previous question. For only a specific file, do you know a solution? I am able to change the file name to .shtml

Comment: Please elaborate what you are trying to do more clearly: Do you want to parse a PHP file (AS PHP) into SHTML (SSI) data, and then parse the SSI directives in the PHP output?  Or do you want to have a file parsed for SSI directives, and then have the resulting data parsed as PHP?

Comment: I believe the latter was right. For one of my files, I want to parse both SSI and PHP directly in a single file. The file name could be anything. E.g. this should work, and output "2015 2015": `<!--#echo var="TIME_YEAR" --> <?= date('Y') ?>` Was that more clear? Is this possible?

Comment: That would mean parsing the SSI directives first, and then passing the output to the PHP parser, which is not possible.  The PHP parser operates at the file level (how would you handle opcode caching, output buffering, includes, etc if it did not).

Comment: According to the linked post, there may be work arounds to do the opposite: `<?php echo date('Y').' <!--#echo var="TIME_YEAR" -->'; ?>` Which would have the server parse the PHP output for SSI directives, but I would imagine this is/was either a bug, or largely unsupported behavior, as again, how would one expect this to handle SSI Includes, etc.  If you can get the later to work, I would imagine it would only parse the first file as PHP, and all others (included or otherwise) would be treated as text as is the expected behavior.

Comment: So basically, what you're saying is that this is impossible? What about the linked answer, why does that work? I could do the same probably, but I only want it for one of my files.

Comment: I am saying I believe the order is impossible, it has to do with how the PHP and SSI parsers work.  It is possible for the SSI parser to handle the output stream of PHP, but PHP can not handle the output stream of the SSI parser.  I am sure that, at the command line, it would be trivial to pipe the output of the SSI parser to a PHP process, but this is not something Apache can do.  The PHP parser, when invoked by a webserver, operates at the filesystem level.

Comment: Actually, have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560326/ssi-included-in-php-as-template-not-working?rq=1

This will pipe the output of PHP to the SSI parser.  That looks like that may do the trick.

Comment: I have edited my answer to point out two other pieces of information that may help, and elaborate on exactly what I was saying was not possible, and what is.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. But to be honest, I'm having a hard time understanding it. I'm not very experienced with this stuff, because I'm mainly just a HTML developer. I don't care which one parses the first. I just want it to work, know what I mean? Do you have a concrete suggestion, some lines of code that I could try in `.htaccess`? The reason for doing this is that I'm eventually going to convert the PHP file to full SSI. I'll need both in a transitioning phase. I try to use SSI whenever possible as it's lighter, and this file only contains variables and if-statements, so it should work.

Comment: I'm giving you the bounty if you can help me a little further. I've tried the linked questions to no luck.